# Can I get the value of a .env variable inside UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, jsx

Here`s my .env.local

```
PORT=5001
PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:5001
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=http://localhost:3013/local
REACT_APP_TEST=Test
```

Now i need the 'REACT_APP_TEST' value inside a .jsx file, inside a useEffect.

How can i do that?

Only `process.env.REACT_APP_TEST` doesn`t work

Comment: Did you create your app with `create-react-app`?

Comment: It would be relevant to have more info about your project, the .env files can be handled by dotenv, webpack, create-react-app, nextjs and so on

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Next.js; I was trying to access .env within useEffect. When I ran the code below process.env.TMDB_API_KEY would be undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${process.env.TMDB_API_KEY}`
      );
      const data = await res.json();
    })();
  }, []);
```

I ended up referencing the variable within next.config.js, and then it worked.

```
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    TMDB_API_KEY: process.env.TMDB_API_KEY,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```